# Maven-bundle-plugin: osgi.ee=UNKNOWN

Tags: maven, osgi, java-10, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

When building my OSGi bundles with JDK 10, maven-bundle-plugin (3.5.1) generates the following manifest attribute:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(osgi.ee=UNKNOWN)"
```

This fails runtime:

```
Unresolved requirements: [[com.mycompany.mybundle [1](R 1.0)] osgi.ee; (osgi.ee=UNKNOWN)]
```

When building with JDK 9, I get the expected:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=9.0))"
```

I set the source and target versions for maven-compiler-plugin to '1.9' and '10' respectively.

At the moment, I'm using a workaround to stop the plugin from adding `osgi.ee` to the manifest:

```
<configuration>
  <instructions>
      <_noee>true</_noee>
  </instructions>
</configuration>
```

.. but I would rather have the correct Java 10 requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a more recent version of maven-bundle-plugin based upon Bnd 4.0 which added support for Java 10 class files.

Comment: It turns out the latest version of maven-bundle-plugin available as of today is 3.5.1 which is only based upon Bnd 3.5. So you need to get the maven-bundle-plugin devs to update. Or you can migrate to bnd-maven-plugin from the Bnd team. But note that is it configured and operates in a different way than maven-bundle-plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5879 to follow up with the Felix team.